# Inserting BLOB data in HSQL via .sql

Tags: java, hsqldb, spring-boot-test

I'm writing integration tests in Spring Boot app and I'm using in-memory HSQL db for that. Because of some requirements I need to insert some BLOB data via `db_data.sql` and I'm searching for the best solution. What I'm using right now is `LOAD_FILE('full_path')` method, but I don't think I can proceed with that. Problems I see:

1. I cannot change the way tests are executed, so I cannot set `textdb.allow_full_path` to `true`. I mean, on my local machine I am and I'm using it, but it cannot be propagated to other environment. I tried to use `System.setProperty("textdb.allow_full_path", "true");` in `@BeforeAll` method, but it doesn't seem to work. I even tried to set it to `false` with `true` passed as VM option and it worked, so I guess my `setProperty` does literally nothing from database perspective.
2. I cannot use absolute path on different machines and tests are meant to be executed in many different places.

I have some dirty workarounds and in general I'm able to run the tests, but inserting blobs via `sql` will be ideal for my purposes. Of course I cannot switch from HSQL to anything else.

**EDIT**

Loading data from file is not strict requirement for me, some of the data is dummy. I can pass basically everything in my `INSERT` statement, text, numbers, whatever.

Comment: Have you considered using H2 instead of HSQLDB?

Comment: @MauricePerry I unfortunately cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

The textdb.allow_full_path is processed during static initialization of one of the HSQLDB classes. It should work so long as the property is set prior to any access to HSQLDB.

You can insert long hexadecimal strings for the blob data. For example:

```
 INSERT INTO mytable (id, blobcolumn) VALUES 2, 'abcdef'
```